# LaTex table in knitr with complex structure (rotating multirow text, removing column separators)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kableextra

I need to create a latex table in RStudio for pdf output with the following structure:

[image]

This table was created for html output with the following code:

```
mat <- data.frame(a = c("column header","column header"),
                  rowx=c("row1","row2"),b = c("a","b"),
                  c = c("x","y"))
kable(mat, align = "c",col.names = c("","","v1","v2")) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, 
              position = "left",font_size = 12) %>%
column_spec(1, bold = T,width="2em",extra_css="transform: rotate(-90deg);") %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "row header" = 2))
```

I need to create a similar structure with LaTeX tables.

His is how far I got:

```
mat <- data.frame(a = c("column header","column header"),
                  rowx=c("row1","row2"),b = c("a","b"),c = c("x","y"))
kable(mat, align = "c",col.names = c("","","v1","v2")) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left",font_size = 12) %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "none") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "rows" = 2))
```

[image]

So I still need at least 2 more things:

- rotate the label in the very first column
- remove the spurious leftmost column separator in the second row.

Can this be achieved with kableExtra commands and parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot with `huxtable` (my package):

```
as_hux(mat, add_colnames = TRUE) %>% 
      insert_row(c("", "", "rows", "")) %>% 
      merge_cells(3:4, 1) %>%  
      merge_cells(1, 3:4) %>% 
      merge_cells(1:2, 1:2) %>% 
      set_rotation(3, 1, 90) %>% 
      set_bottom_border(0.4) %>%  
      set_bold(1:2, everywhere, TRUE) %>% 
      set_wrap(3, 1, TRUE) %>% 
      set_bottom_padding(4, -1, 48) %>% 
      set_bottom_padding(3, -1, 30) %>% 
      set_row_height(c("1em", "1em", "1.5em", "1.5em")) %>% 
      quick_pdf()
```

I have to admit, this took a lot of tweaking. TeX tables are hard to understand....

[image]